# Error al pasar una variable a otro ViewController Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

En el codigo al modificar una variable de otro ViewController me funciona en el caso de que le asigne un string ya fijo pero si intento pasar una variable de esa vista no me reconoce la variable, es como si estuviera vacia, adjunto codigo:

```
class ViewControllerMainPPT: UIViewController {

var figura = " "
@IBAction func piedra(_ sender: UIButton) {
    figura=sender.currentTitle!


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerFinalPPT
    {
        vc.eleccion = "Papel"

    }
}
```

}

La variable figura ya esta asignada y si haces un print en la funcion piedra se ve como se le asigna correctamente pero al hacer el print en el el prepare es como si estuviera vacia, alguna solucion?

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no proporcionas mucha información espero te ayude lo siguiente.
Posiblemente estas mandando con un segue desde el botón al siguiente controller, este segue se ha de llamar antes del evento del botón, es por eso que no toma el valor de la variable al asignarla.

lo que debes hacer es hacer el continue del segue manualmente en el evento del botón.

Primero si tienes este segue a si, eliminalo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después agrega el segue desde el propio Controller:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se debe ver de esta manera al seleccionar el segue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez agregado bien el segue asignale un nombre al segue (como en la imágen) y lo llamas directamente desde el evento de onClick:

```
  @IBAction func piedra(_ sender: UIButton) {
    figura=sender.currentTitle!

    // pasas al siguiente segue indicado
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "misegue", sender: self)

}
```